# How to put a video above a background image using a VideoView?

Tags: android

Is there any way to put a `VideoView` (which plays an MP4 file) above an image (which is the background of my app) ?

In other words, is there any way to put some transparency on my VideoView in the aim that the image be visible through the VideoView ?

Every time I try to put a `VideoView` over an `ImageView`, the `VideoView` hides a part of this `ImageView` (I tried to put an alpha on my `VideoView` but it doesn't work).

Comment: You should show screen shot of what's happening? and what you want to look like?

Comment: @MKJParekh Sorry ! I must not be clear enough! I would like the VideoView to have some transparency to make my background visible through my VideoView

Comment: I dont know how to make semi transparent videoview, But I guest you should do like , make semi-transparent background and put it over the video-view and that will be easy